# CSS to HTML linking bug

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, linker, stylesheet

I can't link external css file to html

The HTML file is situated in folder "header", css file header.css is also situated in this folder.

Heres the css code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css" />
        <title> <?php echo $title; ?> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> <?php echo $header; ?> </h1>
        <div id = 'myOrgButton'>
            <form method="post" action="../../controllers/MyOrganisation">
                <input type="submit" value="My Organisation" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id = 'logoutButton'>
            <form method="post" action="../../controllers/<?php echo $action; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $action; ?>" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr/>
```

The php is here because this is header is php view that i am loading from controller.
I tried defining absolute path, placing css in different folders, nothing works.

When the css is embedded in html with  tag it works perfectly, so i guess the problem is with linking.

**Update**
I've added full html code.

Comment: are you expecting an H1 to show in the title?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the CSS file on the server? It's possible it cannot be read by anyone. Also, use Firebug/Web Inspector to check the console to see if you are getting a 404 on the CSS file.

Comment: When i am exploring CSS tab in fireBug, no rules are present.
In HTML tab, when i try to expand link: i get 404, what that could mean?

Comment: Well, if you can host ur code somewhere, it will be easy to help you out

Comment: 404 is when the file's not found. Are you sure you're saving it to the correct folder?

Comment: Yes, header.css and header.php are situated in one folder on server

Comment: It means the browser cannot GET the CSS file. I would check that your file is there, and named correctly.

Comment: With which browsers does the problem occur? Only in Firefox? By the way, why are you mixing HTML and XHTML in the same file? That is never a good idea. The two are not interchangeable!

Comment: it doesn't work both on FF and IE. I checked the files, name correctly, situated in one folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a view from code igniter, the file system path to that folder is probably not the same as the URL path. First of all, you need to put it in a folder that is accessible over http. I'm not familiar with Code Igniter's implementation of this, but you should have either a "media" or "assets" folder where you put all your CSS and static images. Then, you should make the `<link>` href relative to the domain.

So, if your folder structure looks like this and your "assets" folder is at the root:

```
assets/
  images/
  css/
    header.css
```

Your CSS include should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/header.css" />
```

Comment: you were right, only the link should have been
"assets/css/header.css" Working perfectly now